# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, cmd

MySQL was working fine yesterday but today when I tried connecting to MySQL with Python, I recieved this error. I tried to open MySQL Command Line but it closes right after I input the password even though MySQL service is running. So I can't run any MySQL queries through the command line.

I am definitely sure the password for the root account is correct, but I tried leaving the password and the user blank but it still gives the same error. I tried to change the password through the Installer, but whenever I try to configure the password it asks me for my old password, when I enter it this error shows up:[image]

Hovering over the X the error states

```
MySQL Server is not running, a connection cannot be established.
```

As I said before, MySQL service is actually running. I am unable to change the password through cmd as well, through

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqladmin -uroot -p password
Enter password: *****
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

I have tried using the password blank as well as the user blank in all of these as well. Port is 3306. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The Python code I used to connect was:

```
qtdb = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", 
        password = "mysql", database = "misc", port = "3306")
```

Comment: Could this be a port number issue? What port is MySQL listening on?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Port is 3306.

Comment: Maybe you need to set python to connect to the unix socket instead. If it's working locally, it's a python error. Can you show the script you run to connect.

Comment: @DanielW. I can't log in through CMD either, it gives the same error, and the Command Line closes right after I input the password, so I don't think it is a Python problem.

Comment: Fogive me, but if the error messages Keep saying MySQL is not running, what makes you think it actually is running

Comment: `I tried to open MySQL Command Line but it closes right after I input the password` That normally happens when you enter an invalid password

Comment: @RiggsFolly MySQL service is running in services,msc, I thought that means it is running. Also, I'm sure my password is correct, but even then I can't change it.

Comment: In my experience, is related to 2 issues: 1: check the service (services.msc > mysql80) is loggin in the proper location and user; and 2: is related to a password forgot, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. I used this guide to change my password:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html